# or is not valid C++ : why does this code compile?

Tags: c++, or-operator

Here is a very simple C++ application I made with QtCreator :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    if (a < 1 or b > 3)
    {
       return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To me, this is not valid C++, as the keyword *or* is not a reserved keyword.

But if I compile and run it, it works fine without any warnings ! The exit code is 0 and if I change b = 4, the exit code is 1 !

I'm not including anything to make sure there is no hidden define.

This is really strange to me. Is this something Qt is defining ? I didn't find anything in the documentation regarding that.

Comment: What do you mean well spotted? or **is** a keyword in C++.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis I think *`well spotted`* means the *`why does this code compile?`* part of the question: Some compilers need `#include <iso646.h>` and some not. Most (if not all) IDEs don't highlight these new "keywords".

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators#C.2B.2B_operator_synonyms):

> C++ defines keywords to act as aliases
>   for a number of symbols that function
>   as operators: and (&&), bitand (&),
>   and_eq (&=), or (||), bitor (|), or_eq
>   (|=), xor (^), xor_eq (^=), not (!),
>   not_eq (!=), compl (~).

As [MadKeithV points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433345/or-is-not-valid-c-why-does-this-code-compile/1433393#1433393), these replacements came from C's iso646.h, and were included in ISO C++ as operator keywords. The Wikipedia article for iso646.h says that the reason for these keywords was indeed for international and other non-QWERTY keyboards that might not have had easy access to the symbols.

Comment: Cool - I have been writing C++ since the early 90's and I had no idea about this. I'm not likely to ever _use_ it, but it's good to know.

Comment: I didn't know about it either, until I looked. It seems awkward to use, and I'm sure there are a lot of people out there who write C++ and don't know about it.

Comment: I believe that these were added to help people with other-than-English keyboards that may not have all of the symbol keys (&, |, etc).

Comment: +1. Some guys on IRC did this some day: `struct y { compl y(); };` :)

Comment: I've actually started recently using <ciso646> (the proper way to include iso646.h in a C++ program) in some places, especially unit tests. For example: `if (!someCondition)` looks much better to me as `if (not someCondition)` since sometimes at a glance the ! gets lost next to the parens.

Comment: @FelixDombek It is needed if your compiler does not conform to the standard, and many compilers over the years have not. :) I don't remember what compiler I was using in '09 but I did need the include. That said, not sure I'd recommend this practice to others, in hindsight -- especially given the inconsistent naming of the alternate forms.

Answer (score 17):

`or` is a C++ keyword, and you're allowed to use it instead of `||`. There is no magic.

The same goes for `and` and most other logical operators. It's generally best to stick to the commonly known names though, to avoid confusion like this. If you use `or`, someone will wonder "why does this compile" ;)

Comment: Old answer, I know, but I just want to be cool and pedantic an point out they are not keywords, but alternative tokens. Boy do I feel cool being picky and annoying. </sarcasm>

Comment: Oh right, I didn't realize that distinction. But yeah, looks like you're right. :)

Comment: @GManNickG: They are keywords (at least in the current working draft): Section C.5.2.3:  "The tokens and, and_eq, bitand, bitor, compl, not_eq, not, or, or_eq, xor, and xor_eq are keywords in
this International Standard (2.11). They do not appear as macro names defined in <ciso646>."

Answer (score 8):

[iso646.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso646.h) defines a number of operator alternatives - it's part of the C++ standard.

Comment: `<iso646.h>` is empty in C++.

Comment: It is not in Visual Studio 2003 through 2010 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw6140c5%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Let me rephrase: the file is empty as far as C++ compiler is concerned. Check the sources, you'll see that the macros are conditional on `__cplusplus` macro not being defined.

Comment: Unless _MSC_EXTENSIONS is defined

Comment: MSVC doesn't implement a lot of stuff added since the 1989 C standard.  <iso646.h> was added as part of the 1994 changes, along with various wide-character headers and the like.