# C++ and,or,not,xor keywords

Tags: c++, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The written versions of the logical operators.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators)

I notice that C++ define keyword `and`, `or`, `not`, `xor`, `and_eq`, `or_eq`, `not_eq` and `xor_eq` as an alternative to `&&`, `||`, `!`, `^`, `&=`, `|=`, `!=` and `|=`. and they're rarely used! What's wrong? Are they not portable?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators

Comment: Upvote, because even though it is the same question, your title was clearer to me. (I stumbled upon the `not`-keyword without knowing it existed.)

Comment: At least Visual Studio 2015 CTP 6 did not like `or` or `not`.

Comment: One problem for me is that I can never remember if `and` means `&` or `&&`. So what is the answer to `5 and 6`? 4? Wrong, it's 1. Even if `x = 5; x and_eq 6` is 4. So I prefer `&` and `&&`. More consistent.

Comment: @Mr Lister strongly disagree. One should use `&` and `|` when you're about to crunch bits, and one should use `and`, `or` and `not` when your intention is to write a boolean condition.

Makes for much more _clean code_

Comment: @Ichthyo: He has a valid argument that the alternative name for `&=` should have been `bitand_eq` rather than `and_eq`.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They come from C AFAIR from times when it was not known what special symbols are on the keyboard. So to have portable language they were defined so anyone can use C even if they used keyboard with no `&`, `|`, or `^` (etc.).

Nowadays when QWERTY is a standard (with AZWERTY & co. as variations) it is no longer an issue.

PS. And of course for obfuscation code competitions ;)

Comment: PPS. And to start discussions about consistency, see `and_eq` vs `bitand` ;)

Comment: Which header or standard are they defined in??? Once upon a time, I was using `MSVC 2010` and ended up defining my own `not` and so on...

Comment: @Top-Master I think they are part of syntax as keywords?

Comment: Thanks! I found somewhere that previously `<iso646.h>` for `C` or `<ciso646>` for `C++` was required to be included (not supported by `MSVC` though), and that nowadays maybe since `C++17` and later, they are alternative tokens (without any `#define`).