# Replace && and || in c++ with AND and OR

Tags: c++, logical-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C++ and,or,not,xor keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393673/c-and-or-not-xor-keywords)

I think the title says it, but to expand a little:

Is there a way to replace the && and || operators in your code with "AND" and "OR". It makes it a little more readable, and since im the only one working on the project, I am curious as to whether this can be done. This way instead of writing

`if(is_close_enough(enemy) && attackReady(attack))`

I can use

`if(is_close_enough(enemy) AND attackReady(attack))`

I am using VS2010 as my IDE and C++ as my language.

Thank you for your help

Comment: #define AND && // thats it. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/teas0593(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: my opinion: you should try and learn to read *standard* code that uses &&, instead of adapting it to what you are accustomed to. being able to read code is as important as being able to write code

Comment: @AndyProwl That's what I would do. You'll need this anyway.

Comment: @AndyProwl The tokens `and`, `or`, etc. are in the C++ standard and have been since the beginning.  They are completely standard, and the only reason not to use them are coding conventions of your project *(which would dictate things like indentation as well, which are similarly subjective)*.  Or if you want to compile your code with a C compiler, but then pretty much every actual real feature of C++ is out as well.  I prefer the words, myself...especially `not`.

Comment: @HostileFork: I did not know this and I'm glad I learned something new, but i still stand by the spirit of my comment. plus, "and" may be standard, but "AND" is not.

Answer (score 9):

The language already defines `and` and `or` keywords, along with quite a few others, which are for this purpose.

Comment: but does VS2010 support that?

Comment: Only one way to find out.

Comment: you have a point :) but since you are the one who gave the answer, I supposed you checked that, because the question maker specified that he is working on VS2010. so I did that myself and the answer is "no, it does not support it". which makes your answer informative (i am upvoting it, i did not know that) but useless for the question maker

Comment: VS2010 *does* support these keywords, but only if you disable Microsoft extensions. *Not* supporting them is an extension... :-)

Comment: @BoPersson: that's kind of hilarious, but thanks for pointing it out :-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the preprocessor, but please don't.  It makes your code *less* readable, not more.

```
#define AND &&
#define OR  ||
```

If you want to use a language with different keywords, just use a language with different keywords.  This kind of hacking will only end in tears.

Comment: That's an opinion. but I would say it's a bad habit to do that cause one day he may want to work with other people...

Comment: For sure - even just copy/pasting code to ask a question on SO will cause him grief.