# Are "not, and, or, not_eq.." part of the C++ standard? (And why might they be used or avoided in code?)

Tags: c++, syntax

So it looks like all these: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ciso646/ are keywords in c++.

My question is. Is this a part of the c++ standard?

Can I rely on this to be supported by major compilers? I know gcc does support these keywords.

Finally, perhaps this is more a preference or style question, but are there any advantages to using the keywords over the standard operators (!, !=, && ... etc)?

Comment: "are there any advantages" Not really. I would question code that uses them.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus I can see that one would sometimes want to use `not` in a condition since it's less easily overlooked than `!`.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus Feel free to question all my code. Should we take this to the chat? What weapon do you choose?

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Bananas.

Comment: My "complaint" about these operators is there is no corresponding `eq/is_eq` (I'd happily trade in the bitwise forms I avoid) :|

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is. Is this a part of the c++ standard?

Yes.

> Can I rely on this to be supported by major compilers?

Yes. But MSVC doesn’t support this by default, you need to [pass it the option `/permissive-`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/11/16/permissive-switch/) (or, though this is buggy and outdated, [`/Za`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k0w269d.aspx)), which disables Microsoft language extensions. It seems a good idea to enable this option for almost all C++ projects anyway, it’s just a shame it’s off by default.

> but are there any advantages to using the keywords over the standard operators

In general, no. But in the case of `and`, `or`, `not`, many (though probably not most) people find it more readable. Personally I recommend using them.

If you absolutely want the code to compile on MSVC without the `/permissive-` flag, `#include <ciso646>` (which is a standard header that’s empty on complying C++ implementations, but adds macros for the operators on MSVC).

Comment: In gcc, are the keywords just macros that expand to the operators?

Comment: @anio They are not macros, they are preprocessor preprocessing tokens.

Comment: More readable for who? Most experienced C-family coders will do a double-take at code containing these operators instead of `&&`, `||` and `!`, which they are extremely used to seeing. I would argue they are *less* readable for coders, and coders are who you should be targeting when you think of writing "readable" code.

Comment: @meagar Most languages use keywords for logical expressions, either exclusively or as an allowed alternative. C# and Java are the only ones which don’t allow this, off the top of my head (but I’d wager there are more). C programmers may not be used to it but the same argument is justified to ban other good features, and it doesn’t hold any sway with me. `not x` in particular is more readable than `! x` because it makes the operator more visible and less likely to be overlooked. And I think `a and b` makes it nicely clear that we’re dealing with logical conditions, as opposed to (say) numbers.

Comment: I'm not arguing for other features, I'm arguing that for an experience programmer `&&` should be more readable than `and`. It's what someone experienced with C-style languages expects to see gluing together two variables in an `if` statement.

Comment: Well, I’d describe myself as an experienced programmer, and most of recent programming I’ve done was in C++, and I definitely find `and` more readable than `&&`. On a related note, it annoys the heck out of me that Perl, PHP and Ruby assign different priorities to these operators (but I understand the reason).

Comment: readability depends on the context. Especially the ! often bears the danger of being overlooked. Just consider `return !someThing.isValid();` vs `return not someThing.isValid();`

Answer (score 7):

> Is this a part of the c++ standard?

Yes.  See the table in section [lex.digraph].

> Are there any advantages to using the keywords over the standard operators?

My understanding is that the original digraphs (`<%` instead of `{`, etc.) were introduced to allow people with simple keyboards to be able to write C code ([Wikipedia corroborates this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraph_%28computing%29)).  Perhaps the same rationale applies for `not_eq`, etc.  But AFAIK, there is no good reason to write such stuff nowadays (unless you're coding on your smartphone), not least because 99% of programmers don't know it's valid C++!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are supported.

In terms of the second half of your question they can lead to more readable code especially when dealing with bitwise operators as well as logical operations at the same time for example:

```
if( a & 1 == 0 || c | a == 2 );
```

vs

```
if( a & 1 == 0 or c | a == 2 );
```

Comment: I disagree about bitwise operators. `bit_and` isn’t more readable than `&`, in the same way that `a plus b` isn’t as readable as `a + b`. I *do* agree that it makes logical expressions more readable.

Comment: Oh, I didn't make it clear I ment when there are logical operations mixed with bitwise.

Comment: I wouldn't mix-and-match for the sake of readability. Stick to one type of operator and the maintainers of your code won't have to do a mental context switch every time your operators change.

Comment: @meagar What mental context switch?! Mixing the operators is a *good* thing. Other languages don’t seem to consider that there’s a harmful context switch happening.

Comment: @Konrad Perhaps a bias has crept into my thinking as I've been working for the past year primarily in Ruby where `and` and `&&` are *not* the same thing. However, I would still find it easier to read a line of code where operators stand out as punctuation and variables stand out as words, and I would find it extremely distracting for a single line to mix-and-match ubiquitous `&&`-style operators and less-often used `and`-style operators.

Answer (score 4):

They are in the standards, but support is somewhat uneven. Experienced programmers find them less readable than the usual symbols (`||`, `&&`, `!=`, etc.) so unless you just want to make a political statement about the vendors of the compilers that don't support them, they're best avoided.

At least in my opinion, they're also poorly defined. In particular, they're defined in terms of tokens, not logic. They real reason alternative tokens in general (trigraphs, digraphs, and these things) were invented was to allow use of the language on ancient terminals that didn't support the special characters used by the language. These were added to be marginally less annoying that trigraphs and digraphs. I guess they succeed in that respect, but they're still only marginally less annoying, not anything that should be used by choice.

Let's consider a few examples. If you honestly are on one of those ancient terminals, and you want to write code code that passes a parameter by reference, how do you do it?

```
void foo(T bitand param);
```

From that, it should be obvious how you'd pass a value by rvalue reference:

```
void foo(T and param);
```

Stupid and ugly, but I guess at least it settles the age-old argument about `T& param` vs `T &param`--with `bitand` you need to leave spaces on both sides. In return for that, it's misleading, confusing and unreadable.

Oh, and be careful not to spell it as `bit_and` rather than `bitand`. There is also something named `bit_and`, but it's entirely different--`bitand` is a preprocessor token, whereas `bit_and` is a function template defined in `<functional>`. Using the wrong one can lead to some rather confusing compiler errors.

That said, I can think of one situation in which `and`, `bitand`, etc., are probably justified. If (for whatever reason) you can't type in your code, and have to use dictation software instead, it's probably a whole lot easier to get dictation software to enter `and` than `&&`. It's might be more difficult to get it to distinguish between `bitand` and `bit_and`, but the latter is rarely enough used that it's probably not much of an issue.

**Summary**

For a few people, entering code using the accepted symbols really is difficult enough that it's reasonable for them to use word-based tokens instead.

For anybody else, even if they personally find `and` more readable than `&&`, inflicting such code on others would be about like if I decided to name an addition function `biggerate`, because I thought that was a cute name for addition when I was five years old. So, if you like them and you're writing code that you're absolutely, positively certain that nobody else will ever read, sure go ahead and have a blast. Otherwise, using them is a poor idea.

Comment: Again, this is an over-generalisation. I’d describe myself as experienced, and I find `and`, `or` and `not` more readable – particularly `not`.

Comment: It's not an over-generalization, it's a definition. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Microsoft's complier doesn't support them. You can see the [list of keywords here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

It's just a matter of style (and perhaps readability improvement as some readers insist). Personally, I don't see any advantages of using them in place of && and || etc.

Comment: I can see how one could mix up & and &&, so bitand looks useful to me.

Comment: @anio I need to harp on about this, *don’t* use `bitand` instead of `&`. If anything, do it the other way round and replace the logical operators, not the bitwise ones. – See [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11582955/1968#comment15326033_11582990) on the reason why.