# Why does following C++ program print string's ascii values instead of characters?

Tags: c++, string, printing

This program is supposed to store each word given in standard input stream and count their occurences. The results are supposed to be printed afterwards in order followed by their count. As far as I can tell, the program is working otherwise, but the strings are printed as a ASCII values of the characters instead of the characters themselves. What's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>

std::string get_word();

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string word;

    while (std::cin.good()) {
        word = get_word();

        if (word.size() > 0)
            words.push_back(word);
    }

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());

    unsigned n, i = 0;

    while (i < words.size()) {
        word = words[i];
        n = 1;

        while (++i < words.size() and words[i] == word)
            ++n;

        std::cout << word << ' ' << n << std::endl;
    }
}


std::string get_word()
{
    while (std::cin.good() and !std::isalpha(std::cin.peek()))
        std::cin.get();

    std::stringstream builder;

    while (std::cin.good() and std::isalpha(std::cin.peek()))
        builder << std::cin.get();

    return builder.str();
}
```

Comment: Last I checked, C++ did not have the `and` operator...

Comment: @nneonneo: No, [it does](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and).

Comment: "and" is just another way of writing &&, should work on any modern compiler

Comment: Coool. Thanks all for pointing this out. Is && still preferred, though? This is really the first time I've ever seen it in code.

Comment: @nneonneo: The answer to your question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators), they shouldn't be used and basically they exist for keyboards that didn't have `&`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::istream::get()` doesn't return a `char` but `std::ios::int_type` (a typedef for some integer type that can hold all values of `char_type` and EOF) and that is what you insert in stringstream. You should cast the result to `char`.

[std::basic_istream::get](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)