# Strange error while using word variation C++ not operator

Tags: c++, boolean

I have the following check in my C++ code:

```
if (not obj.someBoolean) {
      // some code
} else {
      // some other code
}
```

A print statement or gdb confirms that `obj.someBoolean` (a `bool` variable) is `false`.
Yet the control goes to the `else` block while using `not` operator.

Interestingly, the `!` variety of the operator works correctly when used in the above scenario (goes into the `if` block).

Is this an issue with the way I am using `not`?

*Update (some more details on the scenario):*

Throughout the code I have used `not` in many places. But this is one scenario where this issue comes up (consistently).

Even the following code works (goes to `if` block):

```
bool temp = not obj.someBoolean;
if (temp) {
      // some code
} else {
      // some other code
}
```

This is more like a single random point where it is happening.
I was curious as to why this behavior is caused.

Comment: What compiler and which version of it are you using?

Comment: It's the first time I see `not` and I can't find any references (googling "not" is hard...) Why would you use it if you have `!`?

Comment: @leemes same. But I found this: http://lists.kde.org/?l=kdevelop-bugs&m=123565240514682

Comment: @Fixxxer yes it is. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/not).

Comment: @Fixxxer It's indeed an [alternative operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) keyword in C++. Otherwise the OP would get a compilation error instead of apparently wrong code generated.

Comment: My guess is that the operator precedence isn't equal for `not` vs. `!`. Try to enclose the expression to be negated in parentheses. However, I think that negating `obj` would lead to compiler errors...

Comment: @Fixxxer I assume you didn't see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators) then...

Comment: @eternalthinker Are you sure you don't have a macro `not` defined somewhere?

Comment: Could you provide a small code sample that compiles and reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am using gcc version 4.1.2. There is no macro named 'not'. Also, the same operator is used in other places (See the updated portion of the question).

Comment: @eternalthinker: did you try inspecting the disassembly of the code section ? If you manage to isolate it in a single function it should be "relatively" possible.

Answer (score 2):

I use `not`, `and` and `or` almost exclusively in C++ (I find them more readable and less error prone than their sigils counterparts). They are **strictly** equivalent.

> **§2.6 Alternative tokens [lex.digraph]**
>
> **1/** Alternative token representations are provided for some operators and punctuators.
>
> **2/** In all respects of the language, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token, except for its spelling. The set of alternative tokens is defined in Table 2.

Look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what's wrong with your code. Try this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  if(not false) std::cout<< "true!"; 
}
```

If it prints "true!", the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: This is not a answer, its a comment

Comment: @DenisErmolin there is no answer.

Comment: Then why you posted it as answer?

Comment: @DenisErmolin it doesn't answer the question, but it may resolve the issue, which I think is valid as an "answer on stackoverflow"

Comment: @LewsTherin it is called a testcase. Instead of saying "make a testcase" I wrote it down.

Comment: Similar test with some object involving the `.` operator which is more like the code in the question: http://codepad.org/xb1K16tp