# Linux g++ compile error: error: expected ',' or '...' before '||' token

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Let me start by saying that this compiles and runs fine in Visual Studio.  But when I compile the same file on Linux (g++), I get compile errors for declaration and implementation of overload of the `<<` operator.

The relevant part of the code is extracted below. (It is a .cpp file with Google Test cases in it, and has class and method definitions sprinkled through to support the test cases.)  I elided all but the relevant parts of the code (I hope).

```
class orderrequest : public msg_adapter {
public:
    // ... snip

    friend bool operator ==(const orderrequest &or1, const orderrequest &or2);
    friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, const orderrequest &or);  // compiler error here
};

bool operator ==(const orderrequest &or1, const orderrequest &or2) {
    bool result = or1.symbol == or2.symbol
        && or1.orderQty == or2.orderQty;

    // ...  snip
    return result;

}

// compiler error here
ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, const orderrequest &or) {

    out << "symbol=" << or.symbol << ",orderQty=" << or.orderQty;
    return out;
}
```

The compile throws a few errors, all seemingly related to trying to overload the `<<` operator:

```
EZXMsgTest.cpp:400: error: expected ',' or '...' before '||' token
EZXMsgTest.cpp:428: error: expected ',' or '...' before '||' token
EZXMsgTest.cpp: In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const orderrequest&)':
EZXMsgTest.cpp:430: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token
EZXMsgTest.cpp:430: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
EZXMsgTest.cpp:430: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token
EZXMsgTest.cpp:430: error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
```

Line 400 is the `friend ostream& operator <<` line, and line 430 is the method implementation for the `<<` operator.

Also, I'm not sure why the compiler error references the "||" token.  (I am puttied to server, and I followed some instructions to set locale to "C" which improved output somewhat, but it still doesn't look right.)

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`or` is *reserved* in C++ (§2.12/2 C++11). It's an alternative token for `||` (§2.6/2), so you can't use it for an identifier. Rename the variable from `or` to something else to solve this problem.

Cf. [this existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators) for further details on alternative tokens.

Comment: Thanks! I thought maybe it had to do with use of "or" (I had already made a pass through to rename the class from "or" to "orderrequest"), but I never really thought or was a token used by C++.  You saved me a lot more time hacking changes!