# Purpose of and() function in C++

Tags: c++, c, function, syntax

What is the function of and() in C++ and its syntax?

P.S. I happened to write out and() as a function and the C++ text editor highlighted it.
Even after much searching I could not find its function or the syntax.

Comment: Just because an IDE highlights something doesn't mean that it exists.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I concur, but in this case it was the "Gedit", so I was curious and hence the question.

Comment: @Troy I am not sure if it is indeed a duplicate, as the  question was not related in its entirety; the solution was nevertheless more general, and hence I could not locate it in the first search on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `and` function in C++, it's a reserved identifier, the same as the logical operator `&&`.

> #### C++11(ISO/IEC 14882:2011) §2.5 Alternative tokens
>
> [image]

In C, there's no `and` keyword, but if you include the header `iso646.h`, `and` is the same as `&&` as well.

> C11(ISO/IEC 9899:201x) §7.9 Alternative spellings
>
> The header `<iso646.h>` defines the following eleven macros (on the left) that expand
>   to the corresponding tokens (on the right):
>
> ```
> and     &&
> and_eq  &=
> bitand  &
> bitor   |
> compl   ~
> not     !
> not_eq  !=
> or      ||
> or_eq   |=
> xor     ^
> xor_eq  ^=
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please give some reference link to it?

Comment: @VishalAnand Last time I looked the C++ standard was not online: you had to pay.

Comment: @EJP, There are drafts like N3485 online.

Comment: @EJP I did not know that.
This indeed says the same thing... Wow!
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/83763/2426743)

Answer (score 1):

`and` is not a function; it is an operator. It means the same thing as `&&`. For example,

```
x && y
```

and

```
x and y
```

mean the same thing.

If you try to use it as a function, it will give you an error.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2376456/1223693) for more information on `and`, `or`, etc.