# C++ function returning bool not executed

Tags: c++

Given a C++ function `foo`:

```
bool foo();
```

and the following lines of code

```
bool some_bool = false;
some_bool = some_bool and foo();
```

I observed that `foo()` is not called although it might have side-effects. What is the name of this behavior and is it compiler-dependent?

Comment: `some_bool and foo()` <-- Huh?

Comment: I'm guessing that `and` is a macro that expands to `&&` or something perverse like that.

Comment: @Michael and @TartanLlama It's actually a [valid keyword in C++](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/and), an alias for `&&`.

Comment: @TartanLlama No, `and` is a keyword, synonymous with `&&`.

Comment: Huh, you learn something new.

Comment: `and` has been a language keyword in C++ since the 1998 standard.  It is also a macro in standard C, from C99 on, but relies on `#include <iso646.h>`.

Comment: @TartanLlama: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2376448/14065

Comment: Please don't add the answer in your question. The SO format is Question+Answers. Especially as there's already an accepted answer for this question. You can comment on that answer instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

In your example, `some_bool` is false and so the statement `some_bool && foo()` is always going to be false. So there is never any need to evaluate `foo()`.

Note that this is standard C/C++ and is ***not compiler dependent*** as it can lead to unperformed code as you've discovered.

A better way of writing the code is:

```
bool some_bool = false;
bool foo_result = foo();
some_bool = some_bool && foo_result;
```

Comment: Calling this "better" is naive. The two are different programs, as you pointed out. Your version does not do the same thing as the OP's. So is it automatically "better" if it in fact does not achieve the OP's requirements? (Or vice versa)

Comment: I do not get what you are driving at. The original code does is broken and does not work. The version here does. It is "better" unless the OP's intention is to write broken code.

Comment: Nothing in the question says the code is "broken" or "does not work". This is a question about whether short-circuiting is reliable. Whether you actually want it or not will depend on the circumstances: you cannot say, in general, that one is "better" than the other.

Answer (score 2):

If `some_bool` is already false, then `foo()` will not be called (optimization), since whatever `foo()` returns, the end result is always false.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks for the information. Glad I learn something new.

Comment: Calling it "optimization" makes it sound like an optional compiler behaviour. It's not "optimization". It's a reliable fact of the language semantics that has hard consequences. "Optimization" tends to describe the compiler taking shortcuts _without changing semantics_.

Comment: This is important, since it happens independently of whether you use optimization in your compiler or not.