# Const char and split function

Tags: c++

This is my split function:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string& s, const char delimiter, bool ignore_empty = false){

      std::vector<std::string> result;
      std::string tmp = s;

      while(tmp.find(delimiter) != std::string::npos) {
            std::string new_part = tmp.substr(0, tmp.find(delimiter));
            tmp = tmp.substr(tmp.find(delimiter)+1, tmp.size());

            if(not (ignore_empty and new_part.empty())) {
                  result.push_back(new_part);
            }
      }
      if(not (ignore_empty and tmp.empty())){
      result.push_back(tmp);
      }
return result; }
```

I'm calling the split function like this:

```
vector<std::string> tiedot = split(line, ";", true);
```

Where the line is:
**S-Market;Hervantakeskus;sausage;3.25**

I need to split the string to strings and add them to a vector but I get this

> Error: Invalid conversion from const char * to char

Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: What is `not`  and what is `and`? This is not valid C++.

Comment: @Michael Walz That's what I thought, but I found alternative operators at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative  I hope it's standard

Comment: @MichaelWalz He's just calling his function wrong.

Comment: No his problem is he provided a const char * string literal to an argument taking a const char. Isn't this interesting... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/not

Comment: Where did you learn "not" keyword? I've never seen it but I like it.

Comment: For anyone interested in these keywords: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376448/the-written-versions-of-the-logical-operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
vector<std::string> tiedot = split(line, ';', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a split function I found on stackoverflow some months ago.

```
std::vector<std::string> fSplitStringByDelim(const std::string &text, char sep) 
{    
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
size_t                   start = 0, end = 0;

//until u find no more delim
while ((end = text.find(sep, start)) != std::string::npos)
{
    //if string not empty
    if(text.substr(start, end - start) != "")
    {   
        //push string
        tokens.push_back(text.substr(start, end - start));
    }

    start = end + 1;
}
//avoid empty string
if(text.substr(start) != "")
{
    tokens.push_back(text.substr(start));
}
return tokens;
}
```

You can call this function with:

```
vector<std::string> tiedot = fSplitStringByDelim(line, ';');
```

Comment: That does not answer the question at all.