# Difference between "&&" and "and" operators

Tags: c++, logical-operators

I saw [alternative operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative) (like `and`, `or`, `not` etc.) when browsing cppreference.

They are alternatives to "normal" operators like `&&`, `||`, `!` etc.

I examined the assembly for code that uses `&&` and `and`. Both versions generated the same assembly.

**Code :**

```
#include <iostream> 

int n = 1;
int main()
{
// if(n > 0 && n < 5)
   if(n > 0 and n < 5)
   {
       std::cout << "n is small and positive\n";
   }
}
```

So my questions are:

- What is the difference between the `&&` and `and` operators?
- Where and when do I use `and` over `&&`?
- If there is no difference, then why does C++ introduce alternative operators (like `and`, `or`, `not` etc.)?

Comment: There is no difference. The `and` operator is just an alternative alias for `&&`.

Comment: I find nothing in the standard (final draft C++1z) about `and`.

Comment: @YSC - It's kinda hidden https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.key#2

Comment: @StoryTeller indeed, as if on purpose... I'm I tired this morning or nothing say explicitly that `and` is the alternative form of `&&` specifically?

Comment: I don't think this have even changed among standards - it was always available...

Comment: To rescue you from being downvoted - why in this context may be perceived as primarily opinion based question...

Comment: @W.F. - The why in the last question is not too much opinion based. That of course depends on whether or not it's "why they were needed" and not "why these particular tokens".

Comment: @StoryTeller you might be right - I'm not the downvoter yet I can imagine one could see it that way...

Comment: I think the downvotes were early feedback. Quite common these days on this site.

Comment: "Where and when do I use `and` over `&&`" If possible: *nowhere* and *never*.

Comment: @YSC The mappings are given explicitly in https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.digraph

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> What is the difference between the && and and operators?

There is none<sup>1</sup>. The "alternative" aspect of these operators means that they can be used to construct the exact same expressions from a semantic perspective.

> Where and when do I use and over &&?

This is largely a matter of preference. I'm too used to `&&` to not use it, but can understand if someone finds `and` more readable.

> why does C++ introduce alternative operators?

C++ was designed to be available on a variety of character sets and platforms. Trigraphs, like Bathsheba pointed out, are another example of such a feature. If a character set would not allow `&&` to be written (say, because it simply didn't have the & character) then one can still get by with the alternative representation. Nowadays, it's largely moot.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> Actually, upon further thinking, my answer to your first question can be refined. There is a slight lack of equivalence, pertaining to how tokens are parsed. `&&` doesn't require a space to be parsed as a separate token, while `and` does. That means:</sub>

```
void foo(bool b1, bool b2) {
  if(b1&&b2) { // Well formed
  }

  if(b1andb2) { // ill formed, needs spaces around `and`
 }
}
```

Comment: Has "and" always existed in c++? I don't recall seeing anything other than &&

Comment: @Carlos - I can tell you it exists since at least [C++11](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/lex.key#2). I don't have something close enough to C++03 to compare.

Comment: They are present from the very first C++ standard - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4251699/is-it-okay-to-use-and-or-etc-instead-of but they are so uncommon that VS doesn't enable them by default - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3448279/and-or-instead-of-in-c-code-compiler-feature-or-programmers-f

Comment: @taskinoor: I believe VS implement them using macros, which wreaks havoc in some edge cases.

Comment: @Bathsheba - When does "VS" and "macros" in the same sentence does not spell doom? `min` anyone?

Comment: @Bathsheba Which edge cases? There should be no difference for all intents and purposes. The only thing I could see is that it would make error messages slightly more confusing if somebody attempted to use them as identifiers. But it should never change the validity of a program.

Comment: Sir, nice answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Stringization, for one.

Comment: @T.C. I’m not convinced there’s a problem: It’s unspecified how the alternative tokens are stringised anyway, so whatever MSVC does would be fine.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "It's unspecified how the alternative tokens are stringised anyway" {{citation needed}}

Comment: @T.C. That would be hard, since it’s precisely *not specified*. The inverse works, though; so: please show me where it’s specified (I’m serious: it’s entirely possible that I’ve overlooked something, though I don’t think so).

Comment: @KonradRudolph how does [cpp.stringize]/2 not cover it?

Comment: @T.C. I don’t think so. What is the “spelling” of an alternative token, such as `and`? Is it “and” or “&&”? I think both would be valid (and MSVC will give you one or the other, depending on whether you stringise the token directly or expanded in a macro argument).

Comment: @KonradRudolph It seems common sense to me that the "spelling" of a token is the way it appears in the source text. See also https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.digraph#2.sentence-1 and the accompanying footnote.

Comment: @T.C. Very good find! Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

`and`, `or`, `not`, &c. are examples of the *alternative operators*.

For the full list see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative; the opening paragraph is a *raison d'etre*:

> C++ (and C) source code may be written in any non-ASCII 7-bit
>   character set that includes the ISO 646:1983 invariant character set.
>   However, several C++ operators and punctuators require characters that
>   are outside of the ISO 646 codeset: {, }, [, ], #, \, ^, |, ~. To be
>   able to use character encodings where some or all of these symbols do
>   not exist (such as the German DIN 66003), C++ defines the following
>   alternatives composed of ISO 646 compatible characters.

If I were you I'd shy away from using them, much in the same way as you ought to shy away from using digraphs and trigraphs, even if the latter make for interview fun.

Trigraphs for example are explicitly discontinued from C++17. You might see `and` &c. being dropped in future standards too.

Comment: Well, in defense of those alternative representation, they are readable. Trigraphs were only present to support some weird keyboards that are no longer widely used.

Comment: @StoryTeller: You can say the same thing about some of the operators too, ^ for example.

Comment: Well, yeah. But I feel that comparing them to trigraphs should at least be given an historic perspective too

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword

Comment: @juanchopanza: Oops, thank you, and fixed. Was I born with that misconception?

Comment: I have to get behind you on the suggestion to shy aware from them. I read the cppreference page in full now. `%:include` made my skin crawl for some reason.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I was once asked (at an interview for Goldmans) to write the "hello world" program in the most obscure way I could. And, no kidding, that was my opening gambit.

Comment: I'm actually more impressed that you could use them off the top of your head like that. `and`, `or` and &co are easy. But `%:`? Kudos :)

Comment: I'm just odd. My all time favourite though is using `/**/` in place of a space. Then you can write an entire program without using the space bar.

Comment: When April fool's day rolls around this year, I know what I'm sending in for code review. Hopefully I'll retain my job...

Comment: Chances of digraphs going away is slim, I'd say. Trigraphs are annoying because they are handled in translation phase 1, but digraphs don't have that problem.

Comment: I really see no reason to shy away from `and`, `or`, `not`. They are clear and commonly used in other languages.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Personally I find the distinction between say `&&` and `&` simpler to grasp than say `and` and `&`. Also, not all compilers support the text versions properly. To me their use is idiosyncratic.

Comment: Well when somebody verbally states a logic equation, 
they say "and".
When somebody describes referencing they say "referencing".
Since it more closely matches normal speech I prefer "and" and "&".